# Notification bigText does not wrap on pre-Lollipop

Tags: android

I am trying to create notifications for my application and I am struggled with different behaviour on two Android versions - I am testing on 5.0.2 and 4.1.2. For displaying long text I'm using `NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle` like so:

```
NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
bigTextStyle.bigText("trying to wrap\na very long text");
```

On Android 5, there is wrapped text properly displayed. On version 4, there is not - see provided screenshots. **How can I achieve wrapping text on pre-lollipop versions?** I tried `NotificationCompat.InboxStyle` so far, but that looks differently and I do not want that.

[image: Notification on 5.0.2]
[image: Notification on 4.1.2]

Comment: This may help: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47578/seeing-the-full-text-of-a-long-notification

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

// set icon, title, etc.
.
.
.

// set Message
String longText = "trying to wrap a very long text message";
builder.setContentText(longText);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)   // Jelly Bean
 builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(longText));

.
.
.
```

but this is to wrap a long message, your code looks like you're trying to insert a line break and control how/where the wrapping happens, so this answer might not be helpful.

Comment: nope, that does not solve my problem - it keeps whole text on one line